# Adding padding to a UIView using AutoLayout constraints

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

Imagine a simple UIView like the blue full width container below. It contains a red box and a yellow box.

[image: Simple full width sample]

The red and yellow boxes are inset from the container by 10px (I know it doesn't look like it in the image. Forgive my rubbish artwork). I can achieve this by setting a Left constraint on the Yellow box in relation to the UIView (Blue) with a constant of 10.0.

However is this correct? Should I be using the LayoutMargins property or the XXXXMargin layout attributes? Many of the example I have seen simple offset from the left or right

Comment: do you ever use the Visual Format Language where you could specify that like @"H:|-10-[yellow(==20)]-(>=1)-[red(==20)]-10-|" .. if you want to see how to do that programmatically with VFL then i can paste that in for you.

Comment: actually .. i just read your specification of padding as opposed to offsets per se :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Layout relative to margins is an iOS 8-only feature, and the examples that you see where constraints are set as simple offsets are probably pre-iOS 8. If you're targeting iOS 8 only, then definitely use the margins. To do so, set the `layoutMargins` property of the blue container to be `UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)` to pad the left and right edges by 10, or set the `NSLayoutAttributeLeftMargin` and `NSLayoutAttributeRightMargin` attributes, and then constrain your yellow and red boxes to those margins. See [this writeup](http://carpeaqua.com/2014/07/24/auto-layout-in-ios-8-layout-margins/) for more details.